# MATLAB - plotting vector against a cell array

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to do something like 
   scatter(timesRefined, upProb) 
where timesRefined is a cell array in which each entry is a string corresponding to a time moment, such as 8:32:21.122 and upProb is simply a vector of numbers with same length as cell array. What is the most convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `timesRefined` cell to a numeric representation of date with `datenum`

```
>> timesRefined = {'8:32:21.122','9:30:54.123'};
>> datenum(timesRefined)
ans =

          734869.355800023
          734869.396459757
```

The resulting number expresses a date as days from the epoch. Since you are not concerned with days, just time, and provided your observations are contained within one day, you can simply take the fractional part of the `datenum` output:

```
>> datestr(mod(datenum(timesRefined),1))
ans =

 8:32 AM
 9:30 AM
```

and do `scater(mod(datenum(timesRefined),1),upProb)`

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by [Pursuit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931379/pursuit), you can use the result of datenum directly as your `x` values and use `datetick('x','HH:MM:SS.FFF')`

Comment: Instead of modding the date, you can simply adjust the tick labels using `datetick('x','HH:MM:SS.FFF')`.

Answer (score 0):

[strsplit from the Matlab file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4615-split-delimiter-separated-strings-into-a-matrix) should help.  If all values are numeric, you'll get a matrix back.

```
timestr = '8:32:21.122';
timenum = strsplit(timestr,':');
convmat = [60*60; 60; 1];
time_in_seconds = sum(timenum .* convmat);
```